# Creating array with multiple objects Javascript from XML data

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a problem approaching this problem and I'm unsure in how to solve it. My XML looks like this:

```js
<Order>
  <OrderLines>
    <ProductLine>
      <ManufacturerArticleNo>ARTICLENUMBER</ManufacturerArticleNo>
      <Serials>
        <SerialNumber>
        .
        .
        <SerialNumber>
       </Serials> 
    <ProductLine>
      <ManufacturerArticleNo>ARTICLENUMBER</ManufacturerArticleNo>
        <Serials>
          <SerialNumber>
          .
          .
          <SerialNumber>
       </Serials>
```

What I want to do is create an array, and fill it with objects with articleNumber, serialnumbers. Where I'm stuck is getting all the serialNumbers from a node to the corresponding article number.

Edits after comments:
Expected output: An array filled with the objects with ArticleNumber, Corresponding serial number. One serial number = one object.

Current Code:

```js
  //Create Article List
  var artList = [];
  
  //Get articles
  var nodeArticleNo = xmlDoc.getFirstNode('//ProductLine/ManufacturerArticleNo');
  
  while(nodeArticleNo != null) {
    var artNo = xmlDoc.getNodeText('//ProductLine/ManufacturerArticleNo');
 
    //Get Serials
    var nodeSerialNumber = xmlDoc.getFirstNode('//Serials/SerialNumber');
    while(nodeSerialNumber != null){
      var serialNo = xmlDoc.getNodeText('//Serials/SerialNumber');
      artList.push({ArticleNumber: artNo, SerialNumber, serialNo});
      nodeSerialNumber = xmlDoc.getNextNode(nodeSerialNumber);
      
    }
     nodeArticleNo = xmlDoc.getNextNode(nodeArticleNo);
    
  }
```

This is how I have been trying to solve it but I hate the while in a while and it is not working as intended

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide code you have attempted and indicate which parts were problematic.

Comment: Also it's unclear what output format you expect

Comment: Edited to try and answer your comments